# How to notify user only once if retrofit multiple calls returns what you need?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Retrofit makes a call every X seconds and returns list of objects. 
If any object of a list has what i need it should notify user.

The problem that i can not solve is retrofit makes a new call every X seconds and returns new List of objects. But objects or one of object may be same and if it is true no need to notify user again. How to do this?

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LiveScore> call, Response<LiveScore> response) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainService.this, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    liveScore = response.body();
                    List<Result>results = response.body().getResult();

                    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                        //here i check all object for a match
                        int homeScore = Integer.parseInt(results.get(i).getScores().getFirstQuarter().get(0).getScoreHome());
                        int awayScore = Integer.parseInt(results.get(i).getScores().getFirstQuarter().get(0).getScoreAway());
                        if (homeScore >= 5 && awayScore >= 5) {
                        //if true and
                        // if current position of object previously has      
                        //not notification, notify 
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and maybe naive approach would be something like this :

```
private final Set<Result> uniqueResults = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<LiveScore> call, Response<LiveScore> response) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainService.this, String.valueOf(response.code()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    liveScore = response.body();

    for(Result r : response.body().getResult()) {
        if(uniqueResults.add(r)) {
            // notify user
        }
    }

});
```

You will need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your `Result` class as well.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed.